# Why java.lang.Integer does not expose its private value field?

Tags: java, thread-safety

In my understanding, a `public` and `final` field is effectively a read-only field. As such, exposing it wouldn't affect the immutability of `java.lang.Integer`.

I know that I can access the value through `intValue()` and the performance shouldn't matter once the JIT kicks in and inlines the method call. But, in general, is there some threading reason or something to not have `public final int value` in `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: why define field public when we can define it private. indeed you must follow encapsulation.

Comment: It's best practice not to expose any fields if you can avoid it.

Comment: For the same reason that `String, Byte, Character, Short, Long, Float, Double,` and practically every other class you can think of don't expose their private fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about threading, but OOP. An `int` is a value type, `Integer` is an object. In object-oriented programming (OOP), you should not expose fields of an object, rather create public methods, aka getters and setters.

Even for constants / read-only fields it is a good practice. Think about **encapsulation**, if you expose a method `intValue()` you can still make it return the `int` value, even if the implementation behind it, here the backing field `value`, changes for some reason or you add additional logic for checks, validation or anything else. As you can see, the backing field is an **implementation detail**, which should not be visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.java` extends `Number.java` which is an abstract class. One of the abstract method is

```
public abstract int intValue();
```

Abstraction defines the contacts which implementing class must obey. Hence `Integer.java` provides the implementation of the method. Now if this method is already present then It becomes an obvious choice to hide the field and just provide `intValue()` as a method to get the value of the field. Having both accessible would add to confusion.

Another reason is that new versions of Java are regularly rolled out.  Language developers try their best for backward compatibility,  just imagine today you are using the field and tomorrow it is decided to have some logical operations or checking done before returning the value. Now if the direct field was accessible then it would have been difficult to achieve.